# SQL 08 Row Rank and Partition Filter by Rank

Tags: sql-server-2008

***Help**** This may be a duplicate but I have searched for an answer and could not come up with any results. I made it this for just looking for a little help...

Basically, I have a query that produces my Row Rank and works great but I cannot filter by the Address Rank...

Looking for One row. Any help would be appreciated. 
 Results:

```
 Andress rank      aDDRESS               PO.primOffInd       pIDKEY         
 1                  100 N WEST                 Y               1
 2                  300 N WEST                 N               1
 3                  500 N WEST                 N               1 
 4                  600 WEST                   N               1
```

Would like:     Code below gives me  Address Rank and 4 Rows I need what's displaying below. THis is for thds of rows so I would like to be able to filter by Address Rank

```
 Address rank   Address       PO.primOffInd    Pikdey
 1              100 N WEST      Y               1
```

Comment: You've provided a very long SQL Server query followed by a very short one.  Is the last one (where you say "I created the below and get all Address Ranks as 1 still the same amount of rows.") a replacement for the very long one?  Or a small part of it?

Comment: Actually, you want just one row, the one that has rank 1?  Assuming everything about your long query is correct except that you're getting rows where `AddressRank` > 1, add a HAVING clause after your GROUP BY:  `HAVING AddressRank = 1`.

Comment: The query runs with the Row Rank...

Comment: The query runs with the Row Rank but what I would like to be able to do is filter on Rank = 1. whihc I wrote, this code is commented out above (right after the first piece of code)    So if I comment out the fist row rank and uncomment out the 2nd  piece of code  it give me 10 rows with a Rank of 1. End result should be 1 row with a rank of 1. I tried the Having clause but not sure where I would add.

Comment: Could you add some sample input data and desired result?

Comment: Updated the question. Let me know if it's not clear, thanks

Comment: I tried (SELECT DISTINCT PO.AddressRank, po.pidkey FROM (select po.pidKey, RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY A.pfpDisplayName, PO.PIDKEY 
    ORDER BY  
      PO.PIDKEY
     ,A.pfpDisplayName
     ,PO.primOffInd desc
     ,PO.OFFMSTRKEY desc
     ,po.spclCd
     ,po.spclDirDesc
     ,UI.UNIQUEID) AS AddressRank FROM rptProvOff AS PO)AS PO WHERE PO.AddressRank = '1') AddressRank but get and error  Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT RANK() OVER
        (PARTITION BY A, PO ORDER BY PO, A, i, c, d, l, UI.UNIQUEID) AS AddressRank /* actual column names were obfuscated for security considerations */
        ... /* the rest of the query minus the order by clause */
    ) as T
where AddressRank = 1
order by uniqueId desc /* ui is not a valid alias here so I removed it */
```

Btw, I assume the other columns you desire are available in the query. I'm don't think that DISTINCT is adding any value since (I gather) that the ranking column is *probably* making all the rows unique. I suggest removing it.

Comment: I removed a lot of the query so it wouldn't be confusing. Going to add it back in the question as I am still not sure of next steps

Comment: I'm sure. I editted the question. The query runs as it but would like to be able to filer on AddressRank of 1

Comment: And another comment regarding `DISTINCT`. It appears you were using the `GROUP BY` to accomplish that same thing. Ignore my previous comment about the subquery but I think your grouping is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to filter out the record with rank = 1 you can wrap your query in another query and use a where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  -- insert your query that generates the ranking here...
) AS t WHERE t.AddressRank = 1
```